# Include quoted messages history in PHPMailer body

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a system that sends e-mails through PHPMailer, and saves relevant messages data in a local DB (message-id, body, recipients, CCs, headers, etc..).
In this DB we save also **incoming** messages data, through a different process.

Now when I send an email that is supposed to be a reply to a previous message, I would like to include the whole history of thread quoted messages, right in the body.
With a PHP function, I'm able to get from DB all messages history in the correct in/out order, with their bodies, dates, sender/recipients, message-IDs, and so on.

For instance, here I'm sending a message with body "Sounds Good!":

```php
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.example.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'john@doe.com';
$mail->Password = 'password123';
$mail->setFrom('john@doe.com', 'John Doe');
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Meeting';
$mail->Body = "Sounds good!";
$mail->Send();
```

Looking at messages raw data in my E-Mail client, seems that quoted old messages are included within the body of message.

If this is the right thing to do, and assuming that in the DB I have all the necessary data for this, is there a way to "pack" the `$mail->Body` property of PHPMailer to include old messages properly? Or has PHPMailer a method for this purpose?
Something like:

```
Sounds good!

On Mon 6 February 2023 at 11:06 Jane Appleseed <jane@appleseed.com> wrote:
> Sure, shall we at 3?

> On Mon 6 February 2023 at 11:04 John Doe <john@doe.com> wrote:
> > Can we met tomorrow?
```

Or using `$mail->Body` isn't the proper way?

Comment: The quoted messages are plain text. Just use ordinary string concatenation.

Comment: @Barmar mail clients recognize previous replies (to hide them, display them a certain way, etc). String concatenation is fine, but what about the syntax to achieve this? Is there a standard? Do we need boundaries o things like that?

Comment: PHPMailer doesn't care what you put in the body, and simple formatting like you suggested will work fine, however, email does support some mechanisms for quoting/embedding that PHPMailer does not support (e.g. `Message/rfc822` format message nesting from [RFC1521](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1521#section-7.3.1)) – you would need to use something with more sophisticated MIME structure handling for that.

Comment: It's a de facto standard syntax: Prefix each line of the quotation with `>`. Nested quotations get additional `>`

Comment: _"mail clients recognize previous replies"_ - yes, but they should also already be able to handle "threads", if you are using message IDs correctly ... So all that quoting rather just adds noise, IMHO. If I, as the answering human, would want to refer to _parts_ of what you wrote in particular - then I'd quote individual lines, prefixed with `>`, _within_ the text that I am writing back to you. Just having the full mail you sent me quoted as-is, below my own reply - who does actually benefit from that.

Comment: @CBroe Good point. BTW having the full history of a conversation in the email body helps for instance when you forward a message to someone is not in the conversation, who would otherwise have no references to understand full dialog.